# Java Graphics2D Drawn Text Exported Exactly To SVG

Tags: java, svg

Am trying to export text to an SVG file and have it look similar to what is drawn using java Graphics2D. The precision is crucial for my application meaning the text in both Java and the SVG need to line up. Both the SVG and the Graphics2D texts have the same font(family, style, size) and I can definitely see that the resulting texts are different.

Example: Seems the chars look the same but for some reason the spacing between 'T' and 'e' differ.

**BLACK - SVG Text**

**BLUE - Java drawn Text**

Code for the drawing of text using Graphics2D.

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

String text = "Test";
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 33);
g.setFont(getTextFont());
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

g.drawString("Test", 0.f, 0.f);
```

SVG text

```
<text fill="rgb(0,115,198)" font-family="Arial" font-size="33.0">
  <tspan dy="0" x="0">Test</tspan>
</text>
```

[image: Test Top From SVG; Test Bottom From Graphics2D]

[image]

Any ideas how to change either the SVG(viewed in Adobe) or Java text such that they display exactly the same thing?

**Update:**

Turning kerning does make it like up better but not perfectly.

Example: Seems the spacing between f A is different. But the rest of the text lines up.

Code

```
public void draw() {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    String text = "Test";
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 33);
    Map<TextAttribute, Object> map = new Hashtable<TextAttribute, Object>();
    map.put(TextAttribute.KERNING, TextAttribute.KERNING_ON);
    font = font.deriveFont(map);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

    g.draw(getTextShapeByLine(text);
}

public Shape getTextShapeByLine(String line) {
    AttributedString attstring = new AttributedString(line);
    attstring.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, getTextFont());
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
    TextLayout t = new TextLayout(attstring.getIterator(), frc);
    return t.getOutline(null);
}
```

This draws the text with kerning and allows scaling on the graphics context. But, now the spacing(white-space) is sometimes messed up between certain characters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like one renderer supports kerning and the other doesn't. I imagine changing to VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_OFF may therefore help. Fractional metrics is different from kerning but that's the closest you can get to it in J2SE.

Comment: I think that kerning is OFF for the Java rendering (which is the default), but it can be turned on. I'm guessing it would then render correctly. Information here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/textattributes.html

Comment: @Frecklefoot This does make it look more similar. But in my application I need to be able to zoom in/out in an editor which applies an Affinetransform, keeping the font and text the same, but when zooming in characters start moving closer and closer until the eventually overlap.

Comment: Well, a couple things come to mind. One is to render the fonts to a bitmap (an image) and just zoom in on that. That would preserve the apparent font rendering without altering the distance between characters. I also found this http://java-sl.com/gp_effects.html (if you find my comments helpful, please upvote them :)